# Using Mocha to test file download using file-saver in a react project, gives "ReferenceError: HTMLAnchorElement is not defined" error

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, enzyme, filesaver.js

I am trying to test the file-download on click of a button in a react project, which uses 'saveAs' from npm file-saver https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

The function for downloading is as follows :

```
const downloadFile = (csvData) => {
    const dataFile = new Blob([csvData], {
        type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'
    });
    saveAs(
        dataFile,
        `filename.csv`
    );
};
```

A button component uses this function which is passed as prop to it and is called 'onClick'.
The test is as follows :

```
describe('<ExportButton/>', () => {
    let wrapper, props;

    beforeEach(() => {
        props = {
            ...defaultProps,
            handleOnClick: expect.createSpy(),
            downloadFile: expect.createSpy().andReturn(() => {})
        };

        wrapper = shallow(<ExportButton {...props} />);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        expect.restoreSpies();
    });

   
    it('should call the downloadFile and save the file in location specified', (done) => {
        wrapper.find('Button').simulate('click');
        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(props.downloadFile).toHaveBeenCalled();
            done();
        }, 50);
    });
});
```

On running the test it gives

ReferenceError: HTMLAnchorElement is not defined
at /node_modules/file-saver/src/FileSaver.js:75:19
at /node_modules/file-saver/dist/FileSaver.min.js:1:106
at Object. (/node_modules/file-saver/dist/FileSaver.min.js:1:154)......

error and test fails.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In your test setup file, try setting this:

```
global.HTMLAnchorElement = window.HTMLAnchorElement;
```

Comment: i already solved it by adding : global.HTMLElement = window.HTMLElement;
                                 global.HTMLAnchorElement = window.HTMLAnchorElement; in set up file, thanks for the answer though.